# Build Node doesn't appear in Team Explorer for a C# DLL project in Visual Studio 2013 linked to TFS-Git

Tags: c#, git, dll, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I've created a TFS + Git project on tfs.visualstudio.com. I've commited my changes and pushed them on Master to the Git repo hosted on TFS.

In Team Explorer, I see the usual "Changes", "Branches", "Commits" and "Settings" Nodes/Menu. However the "Build" node is not there at all.

When creating a MVC 4 application however, the "Build" Node is always there.

It looks like the Build Definition is hosted on TFS for my MVC application but there's no way to create a new one for my DLL Project, inside the IDE or on the TFS web side (in the Build section).

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Should I quit the idea to build a custom DLL using TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it looks like it was a glitch in Visual studio 2013 preview / TFS.

I've copy/pasted a ProcessTemplate generated from an Azure Solution linked to TFS, commited it to Git, deleted it from Git, restarted Visual Studio and magically the "Builds" Node in the Team Explorer appeared as well as the "Work Items".

I guess this is more like a bug in Visual Studio than a manipulation error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the "Source Control" pane. If you click the "Home" icon at the top of the Team Explorer window you should see "Source Code | Commit | Work Items | Build | Settings"... You can then delve into "Build" from there...

Comment: The "Build" menu was not even there. It really was a glitch.